# How can I combine this php statement to get the results of multiple variable inputs?

Tags: custom-field, customization

This is my query, it shows the posts that have meta_key as extra1 and meta_value as test

```
<?php $customkey1 = 'extra1'; ?>
<?php $customvalue1 = 'test'; ?>
<?php query_posts('meta_key=' . $customkey1 . '&meta_value=' . $customvalue1);  ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My question is how can I still show the posts that have extra1 as metakey and test as metavalue but also the posts that have extra2 as metakey and test2 as metavalue in the same query. A combination of two or more variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using WP 3.1, I would recommend using the `meta_query` parameter with the WP_Query class.

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => $customkey1,
            'value' => $customvalue1,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => $customkey2,
            'value' => $customvalue2,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

The meta_query parameter allows for very powerful queries with metadata.

Sources:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: Hi there thanks but it seems that it doesn't working. It continuesly showing me all posts of the blog.

Comment: If you pastebin the code, I'll take a look. Are you using 3.1?

Comment: My bad. Is working! Thank you! Is there a compact-simpler way to handle 10 arrays instead of having it copy-paste 10 times for different variables?

Comment: @Mairy: if your custom keys need to be checked against the same value using the same compare setting, you could create a loop for DRY code.

Comment: Please take a look here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16079/slow-speed-and-high-cpu-usage-for-my-code-how-to-improve-it