# Slow speed and high CPU usage for my code. How to improve it?

Tags: wp-query, performance

this is my code. It gets the variables from the url. It is very slow and sometimes don't even complete. How can I improve it?

Note: Most of the times some of the variables will not have any value. I thought that if I check this and remove it's array from the query it will improve it somehow.

```
$value1 = $_GET['extra1'];
$value2 = $_GET['extra2'];
$value3 = $_GET['extra3'];
$value4 = $_GET['extra4'];
$value5 = $_GET['extra5'];
$value6 = $_GET['extra6'];
$value7 = $_GET['extra7'];
$value8 = $_GET['extra8'];
$value9 = $_GET['extra9'];
$value10 = $_GET['extra10'];

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => extra1,
            'value' => $value1,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => extra2,
            'value' => $value2,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => extra3,
            'value' => $value3,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => extra4,
            'value' => $value4,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => extra5,
            'value' => $value5,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => extra6,
            'value' => $value6,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => extra7,
            'value' => $value7,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => extra8,
            'value' => $value8,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => extra9,
            'value' => $value9,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => extra10,
            'value' => $value10,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch that meta query of this complexity is going to be crazy. I am not sure what you are trying to do without context described, but most likely there are easier way to organize that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is just a typo, but your key variables are missing the `$`. This should trigger a fatal error. Try doing a find and replace to replace `extra` with `$extra` and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Nah, unquoted stuff is treated as unknown constant and cast to string with warning. Won't trigger fatal error.